# How To Update UIProgressView after UITextField DidEndOnExit

Tags: ios

I have a UITextField, which checks a password and then my app loads data from a remote server. While this is happening I would like a progress view to display the progress of the download. My issue is that the UITextField seems to lock up the display until it returns and therefore I cannot update the progress view on the main thread. I also would like an answer without GCD or any other kind of threading as I am using core data and that would probably overcomplicate the app. Is there a way to have the UITextField not lock up the view so that I can update my progressView on the main thread?

Comment: If you're downloading content, you have to multithread.  If you're not, I can't imagine your app being approved by Apple.  The UI should ALWAYS be responsive.

Comment: @nhgrif Do you have any good tutorials for using GCD with CoreData and NSXMLParsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is loading data from a remote server, then you will have to use multi-threading(GCD, etc). Otherwise it just locks up the main thread till the download is finished which makes your app unresponsive.

To keep it simple, use GCD to fetch data(raw `NSData`) and give it to the main thread. Do all your processing on the main thread(core data,  etc) as usual.

EDIT: One more thing, it is not the textfield locking up your UI, it is the download. So I don't think you can do anything other than multi-threading to help you here.

Comment: It isnt the download because the download exists in 7 parts, between each I update the progress view. Do you know any good tutorials on multithreading core data with xmlparsers?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295 is good if you want to learn basics of GCD... Some parsing is also done there, although I think it parses HTML, not XML.